# ClassNotFoundException when trying to connect to SQL server 2005 with Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, classnotfoundexception, sqlconnection

I'm fairly new to database management. I'm just trying to connect to the database and retrieve and display a table in the command prompt. The database is not on my computer. I am fairly certain that the url is the problem. The code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

class transfer{

//driver and DB URLs
final static String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
final static String DB_SQL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "database=DataDB;" + "user=sa;" + "password=1234";

//Database Username and password
final static String user1 = "sa";
final static String pass1 = "1234";

static ResultSet rs;        
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Connection conn_sql = null;
    Statement stmt_sql = null;
    //Statement stmt_ora = null;

//Register JDBC driver      
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
//Open Connection   
    System.out.println("Connecting to SQL database...");
    conn_sql = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_SQL, user1, pass1);

//Execute Query
    String sql_query;

    System.out.println("Creating statement for SQL...");
    stmt_sql = conn_sql.createStatement();
    sql_query = "Select * from attendancesummary";
    rs = stmt_sql.executeQuery(sql_query);
    System.out.println("SQL table details");

    System.out.println("Creating statement for SQL...");

    while(rs.next()){
    //Retrieve data
        int cno = rs.getInt("CardNo");
        int in_time = rs.getInt("entry");
        int out_time = rs.getInt("Exittm");
        String name = rs.getString("Name"); 
        int date = rs.getInt("TrDate");

    //Display data
        System.out.print("Employee ID: "+cno);  
        System.out.print("\tName: "+name);
        System.out.print("\tDate:"+date);
        System.out.print("\tEntry: "+in_time);
        System.out.print("\tExit: "+out_time);
    }       

}
```

}

The database name is DataDB and the table that I want to retrieve and display is attendancesummary. I have set my path as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin";"C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar"

The code compiles fine.. but when I run it, I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
    at java.lang.Class.forname0
    at java.lang.Class.forname
    at transfer.main

I am truly lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException when connecting to MS SQLServer using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407986/classnotfoundexception-when-connecting-to-ms-sqlserver-using-jdbc) And your JDBC url is wrong, you might want to read [Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `sqljdbc4.jar` is missing from your ***CLASSPATH*** while running the code. If you are running this from command line then add the path to `sqljdbc4.jar` in `-cp` switch of `java` command.

If you are running from eclipse, then add `sqljdbc4.jar` in your build path.

Comment: I tried: java -cp -sqljdbc4.jar transfer.. got the following error
Error: Could not find or load main class file transfer

Also, i am running this from cmd prompt.

Comment: You need to add your class with main method as well in the CLASSPATH. For example, if you are currently running from the same directory as your class then use `java -cp <absolute path to sqljdbc4.jar>;. transfer` on Windows

Comment: Just tried:
java -cp C:\Program Files\......\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;. transfer

..still the same error. transfer class is containing the main method.

Comment: Ah! you need to make `transfer` a `public class` ... wonder, how I missed that earlier :)

Comment: I made transfer as public. Tried to run: java -cp <path to sqljdbc4.jar>;.transfer....... I get: Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Microsoft. Know what this means??

Comment: Okay my bad. Finally got past the cannot find main class error! I was tried running java -cp <absolute path to sqljdbc4.jar>;.transfer instead of java -cp <absolute path to sqljdbc4.jar>;.<space>transfer.... monstrous disaster caused by the missing space! Thanks a ton Pat! Making the class "public" and adding main method with classpath did it!

Answer (score 1):

Add sqljdbc4.jar in your classpath.

If you are using Eclipse then you can right click on project -> properties -> java build path.
Go to libraries and click on add external jar.
Then add the jdbc driver jar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not using eclipse. I tried that, got error: could not find or load main class file transfer

Comment: May be there is some configuration issue. JVM is not able to find your .class file(Transfer.class)

Comment: it compiles the program. no isues there. While trying to get it to run i get the error.

Comment: You got the same exception(Driver ClassNotFound)

Comment: Okay, nw the error is different. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:......databaseName:DataDB

Comment: You said that database in not on your computer. Then you need to give IP address of the computer and port no where DB is located. DB_SQL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS:1433;" + "database=DataDB;" + "user=sa;" + "password=1234";

Comment: I am trying that only now.
conn_sql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433; database=DataDB;"+"user=sa;"+"password=1234");.......still the same error. It does print the SOP : Creating statement for SQL...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the JDBC driver to your project class path: example if you are using Eclipse put the jar in the 'lib' folder